# partial image content in the first access

Tags: nginx

I have two nginx servers in different machines serving the same cifs share, mounted with the same options. The files serverd are images.

In one of the servers, the first access to a image file not send the complete image. The content-length are correct in both nginx servers.

For example, the partial image that sends the first nginx: 
http://www.alderia.com/32445166.jpg

The correct image sends the second nginx:
http://www.alderia.com/32445166_2.jpg

If I reload (with shift+control+r) the first image, it's load ok.

Comment: The first thing you should do is to stop using CIFS.

Comment: disable sendfile in this location if enabled: http://nginx.org/r/sendfile

Comment: @citrin same result with sendfile off

Comment: @VBart I have tried with nfs and works ok in both servers, but I have another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499904/nfs-encoding-issue

Comment: Serving files via any network file system (nfs or cifs - doesn't matter) is a bad idea in general. It performs slow and buggy.