# nfs encoding issue

Tags: encoding, nfs, cifs

I have a Celerra NS-20 that export a filesystem with cifs and nfs. The files are written by windows machines.

When I mount the cifs in linux all filename special characters are ok, but when mount the nfs (same filesystem) the filenames special character are broken.

Are there a way to mount the filesystem changing the encoding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the same issue with a new VNX 5300 and the resolution was to enable the NFSv4 protocol in the VNX, by default its only support v3.

For that, edit:

/nas/server/slot_2/config

/nas/server/slot_3/config

And set the line like:

nfs config hivers=4

and restart the datamovers:

server_cpu server_2 -reboot -monitor

server_cpu server_3 -reboot -monitor